# Asymptotic behaviour of a couple of special functions (features exponentials and logarithms)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm dealing with a couple of functions: $n  \log n$, $( \log  \log n)^{ \log n}$, $( \log n)^{ \log  \log n}$, $n e^{\sqrt{n}}$, $( \log n)^{ \log n}$, $n 2^{ \log  \log n}$, $n^{1+1/( \log  \log n)}$, $n^{1+1/ \log n}$, $n^2$.

I want to order them according to their growth rate and express the ordering using asymptotic notation.

Apart from noticing $n^{1+1/ \log n}=n \mathrm e$, I didn't manage to simplify them. Essentially, what I did so far was plugging in large values for $n$ and comparing plots. Like this I came up with a rough asymptotic ordering:
$$n e^{\sqrt{n}} \succ n^2 \succ ( \log n)^{ \log n} \succ n^{1+1/( \log  \log n)} \succ n  \log n  \succ n 2^{ \log  \log n} \succ n \mathrm e \succ ( \log  \log n)^{ \log n} \succ ( \log n)^{ \log  \log n}$$
where $\mathrm f(n) \succ \mathrm g(n)$ means that there is $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\mathrm f(n) > \mathrm g(n)$ for all $n > n_0$. Obviously, this implies $\mathrm g(n) = O(\mathrm f(n))$.

However, what I'm looking for is a little bit more insight. Is it possible to give some meaning to at least some of them?
What I'm trying to do right now is relating each term to a common complexity class. Some are obvious. But what about the two smallest terms for example? Are they in $O(\log n)$ or still linear? How can I fand out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ordering is slightly incorrect, due to the fact that subtle asymptotic differences are frankly difficult to see clearly on the plot. A general advice for this type of problems: when faced with "exponent-heavy" sequences, try comparing logarithms of values instead of values themselves.

For example, let's take a look at $n^2$ and $\left(\log n\right)^{\log n}$. Taking logarithms, we obtain $2 \log n$ and $\log\log n \log n$. Now it's clear why the plot was not very helpful: $\log\log n$ grows unboundedly, but very slowly, and for $n<e^{e^2}\approx 1600$ it's less than $2$.

Similarly, $\left(\log\log n\right)^{\log n}$ is asymptotically bigger than $ne$, since 
$\log\left(ne\right)=\log n + 1$, but 
$\log\left(\left(\log\log n\right)^{\log n}\right)=\log n \log \log \log n$. Needless to
say, it's only visible for rather large $n$ (roughly for $n \geq 5.1 \times 10^7$). So it's not only not $O\left(\log n\right)$, but not $O\left(n\right)$, either.

The last function - $\left(\log n\right)^{\log \log n}$ - is not linear, but it's not $O\left(\log n\right)$, either, as can be shown by analogous argument.

Comment: Ah thanks, your explanation has helped me a great deal, especially the hint to look at logarithms (though I should have thought of that myself...). After going over all the relations again analytically, I noticed that $n 2^{ \log  \log n} = O(n \log n)$, is that correct? If I'm not mistaken, that's the only term other than the obvious ones that belongs to a common complexity class. Also $O(n \log n)$ seems to be the only class containing more than one of these terms. Does the last statement imply that we have $f=\omicron(g)$ whenever $g(n) \succ f(n)$ for these examples?

Comment: You're right - if $\log$ is natural algorithm, then $n\,2^{\log\log n}$ = $ne^{\log 2 \log\log n} = n\left(\log n\right)^{\log 2}=n\log^\alpha n$ with $\alpha=\log 2 < 1$, which is indeed $O\left(n\log n\right)$. I believe rest of your statements is also correct.